# webforms.js vs2012 usage

Tags: gridview, visual-studio-2012

I am new VS 2012 I  am seeing webforms.js  in Bundle.config file. It has GridView.js file.  Is this Jquery gridview or original Asp.net gridview. Also please let me know  If there are any tutorials to use  GridView.js file